# Realistic folded transparent/translucent shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, lighting, shadows

I'm currently modeling a bedroom scene that has very thin curtains over each side of the window. I'm able to make them transmit light from the back side with no issue, however they either cast no shadow or full black shadow.

The curtains are wavy/folded like you'd picture curtains being, and the light is hitting them from an angle that should allow for a shadow to be cast that still shows those folds with a variable density of shadow on the walls/floors.

I've tried editing everything I can think of in the material, combining my Principled BSDF and a Translucent BSDF (as well as trying Transparent) but can't get the shadows to act anywhere close to how they should. I'm using Cycles.

Has anybody successfully created an overlapping translucent shadow before, and how did you do it?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hi :). Could you please add some images comparing your result with real curtains? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a *Mix Shader* with *Transparent BSDF* gets us the shadows we want, but also affects the object's shading in a way we don't want.

[image]

We can fix this using the *Light Paths* node.  The *Is Shadow Ray* output can be used as the *Factor* of the *Mix Shader*.

[image]

You can use the color values of the *Transparent BSDF* to control how much shadow appears.

[image]

Areas with many folds like the dark areas you can see leftover may require more *Total* and *Transparency* bounces under *Render Properties* -> *Light Paths* -> *Max Bounces*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I could have sworn I've tried this exact thing, though. Let me go follow these instructions real quick and see with what I can come up.

Yeah, I absolutely have tried exactly this prior to asking my question. However, I never gave it a test render outside of the viewport, and have only viewed it very grainy-ly. I think that, combined with the fact that my light source isn't hitting at hard enough of an angle to get that result is why it looked incorrect.

Thanks again for your response and help!!

Comment: @Bugiboop glad I could help